# How can i detect face in an image using core image accurately in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

In my application i need to detect face of an image accurately, but i'm not getting accurate output. I used coreimage framework to that.I am not getting the right eye position,left eye position and mouth position somewhere else and even not detecting smile also.

This is my sample code.

```
- (void)drawRect
{
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

    CIImage *img=[CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageView.image.CGImage];
    NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:img];

    for (CIFaceFeature *feature in features)
    {
       CGRect faceRect = feature.bounds;

UIView* face = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceRect];

        [face setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor yellowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
        [imageView addSubview:face];

        if(feature.hasLeftEyePosition)
        {
            UIView* eye = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(feature.leftEyePosition.x,feature.leftEyePosition.y, 20, 20)];
            [eye setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]];
            [eye setCenter:feature.leftEyePosition];
            [mainView addSubview:eye];

        }

        if(feature.hasRightEyePosition)
        {
            UIView* eye = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(feature.rightEyePosition.x, feature.rightEyePosition.y, 20, 20)];
            [eye setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]];
            [eye setCenter:feature.rightEyePosition];
            [mainView addSubview:eye];

        }

        if(feature.hasMouthPosition)
        {
            UIView* mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(feature.mouthPosition.x, feature.mouthPosition.y, 20, 20)];
            [mouth setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]];
            [mouth setCenter:feature.mouthPosition];
            [mainView addSubview:mouth];

        }
        if(feature.hasSmile)
        {
            NSLog(@"you are smiling");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps your picture quality is too bad?  If CoreImage can't find it then it is unlikely that you will be able to with any other method.

Comment: even i tried with images of high quality,for some images it was no detecting face also.@borrden

Comment: "Some images."  Face detection is not a trivial matter.  Sometimes faces just can't be detected for whatever reason (odd lighting, weird angle, etc)

Comment: okey,thank you borrden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flip image on y-axis to match coordinate system used by core image,So that you can get accurate positions